# What does 'admit bearer' mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I imagine what means whole phrase, but 'admit bearer' requires more explanation for me.

> Please **admit bearer** any show free of charge.

Comment: I am curious what steps you took to try to figure this out on your own.Did you perhaps look up **admit** in a learner's dictionary that gave the meaning 'to confess to something' which caused your train to go off the track?

Comment: Without article 'the' and preposition 'to' it seems strange to me and I doubted how to connect words. And of course I knew 'admit' as 'to confess to something' and 'bearer' was new before I saw it.

Answer (score 2):

Here "admit (somebody)" means "let in" or "allow (somebody) to enter". This is the original meaning of "admit".

The "bearer" is the person holding the ticket. It is the agent noun from the verb "to bear". So it just means "Let the person holding this ticket in". It implies that the ticket can be given or sold to another person prior to the show.

A preposition is needed before "any": "Admit bearer to any show..."

Comment: Just to add to the remark about needing a preposition: This is using a very shortened style, common on small documents like tickets ("admit one" is another example that comes to mind, meaning something like "this ticket means we will admit one person to the show"). The one in this question isn't all *that* abbreviated (it uses "please"!), but a more normal English sentence would still use at least one more word: "Please admit **the** bearer **to** any one show free of charge."